# EntityCommandExecutionException:Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: sql, azure, entity-framework-5

I have an EntityFramework select statement which return like some 50K rows. i am getting this exception for this simple select command

```
var db = new DBEntity();
db.CommandTimeout = 350; 
var actCosts = (from i in db.Products
                            where i.productID== productID
                            select i).ToList();
```

the database is in Azure. i have connected through SSMS to know the actual time taking to retrieve the rows it takes 4:30 minutes to bring all data. So i set Commandtimeout  to like 350 seconds. But it didnt worked

is there any performance differences between the above and this one

```
var actCosts = db.Products.Where(t => t.productID== productID).ToList();
```

Comment: did you try to set a larger timeout? SMSS uses other ways of retrieving the data and is probably optimized for this. First try to run a .FirstOrDefault(), see if it returns data in time.

Comment: where are you setting your timeout?

Comment: var db = new DBEntity();db.CommandTimeout = 350;

Comment: edit your answer with the code where you set the timeout. tnx

Comment: also, the query that you use in SSMS to select the data would be useful. maybe there is some issue there.

Answer (score 0):

First try to run a .FirstOrDefault(), see if it returns data in time

```
var actCosts = (from i in db.Products
                            where i.productID== productID
                            select i).FirstOrDefault();
```

If it works, I suggest setting an even larger Timeout, like 1000, and see if your results are returned then.

I believe SSMS uses other ways of retrieving the data and is probably better optimized for this than a simple .ToList() method.